How to convert the data type of date column from a string into integer
Please help me to convert the date column from a string to a integer in pandas.I use parse date=True while calling the data but it is not working on jupyter notebook.The data type of the dates remains the same.
stock_df = pd.read_csv("NFLX.CSV",parse_dates=True)


parse_dates is for dates, not integers, your question is missing a [mre]

Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Thanks sir for the guidance .Actually sir by using parse_dates = ["column_name] we can change the str data type of dates column into Timestamp datatype.

Please share sample data and minimal code to reproduce on our machines. Without, all we can do is guess and take your word for it.
